# consistent legend colours with 2 graphs in powerbi

Tags: powerbi

So I have two charts in powerbi and these two charts are based on two different data sources. However each data source contains a column with numbers from 1 to 10. I want these two columns to be the respective legends for both charts.

My issue is that the legend colours on each graph are different. I.e. The colour for 1 is blue in the first chart but the colour for 1 is red in the second chart.

Any idea how I can synchronise them together?

Answer (score 2):

You can manually set the color for each series - select the visualization, then in the Visualization pane click `Format`, `Data colors` then format each series to suit. Repeat for second visualization.

[image: Screenshot of Data colors in PowerBI Visualization pane]